# how can i get large files to do experimentation

Tags: performance, csv, testing, apache-spark, cluster-computing

I finished creating the first spark application. In order to know its performance i need large files (.csv) to do some tests and experimentation to monitor my application in order to tune it.

We all know that the size of data has a serious impact on results, but all files.csv that i have are small, so i can not trust or confirm results that i get.

How can i get files with large size? help me please

> I need large sizes such:

```
 10 GB, 20 GB, 30 GB, 50 GB, 100 GB, 300 GB, 500 GB.....
```

Comment: Did you try searching for large csv generators? There's a bunch of services out there...

Comment: There are also many large CSV datasets available, you can for example download the 2000 US census data.

Comment: ok i'll try, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Huge data can be generated by Write a data generation code in any language you prefer eg Java, C, C++.

2) Jmeter is also a tool to generate huge data usually used for Performance Testing

Hope this Help!!!..